# Memberfunction pointers and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, pointer-to-member

I am using templates to store memberfunction pointers. But i have a problem right now with inheritance. I dont know if this is a compiler bug or not but when i do

```
&std::map<T1, T2>::size
```

i get a thiscall to std::_Tree instead of std::map. If i do

```
&std::map<T1, T2>::swap
```

i get a thiscall to std::map. (tested on visual studio 2013)

Now looking at the code for std::map it inherits from std::_Tree which defines size but not swap. My question now is if there is a way to get the type show up as __thiscall std::map::* in all cases. Cause getting it as std::_Tree is not really what i want.

Comment: Why do you care? A pointer to member of base class can be used with an instance of derived class.

Comment: because i save those pointers with typeid(class) as the key. and if i query for std::map i want it to give me std::map functions. which is impossible if i get some of them as std::_Tree

Comment: @ACB you're doing something very very wrong on a basic level. Why would you ever do that in C++?

Comment: to bind functions to lua. and it works for everything else

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is nothing you can do. The implementer of the standard library is allowed to inherit methods from base classes as per

> #### 17.6.5.11 Derived classes [derivation]
>
> 1 - An implementation may derive any class in the C++ standard library from a class with a name reserved to the implementation.

It doesn't say either way whether methods (and other members) are allowed to be inherited from a base class, but it is clearly not forbidden.

Even the signature might not be what you expect:

> #### 17.6.5.5 Member functions [member.functions]
>
> 2 - An implementation may declare additional non-virtual member function signatures within a class:
>
> - by adding arguments with default values to a member function signature<sup>186</sup>; [...]
>
> 186) Hence, the address of a member function of a class in the C++ standard library has an unspecified type.

Sorry :)

Comment: that may be so. but is there no way that &std::map::size will return a function pointer to std::map instead of std::tree. i mean i can cast it but that is quite verbose. i mean with &std::map::size i even tell the compiler i want a funtion pointer of std::map

Comment: @ACB Technically, there is no **method** called `std::map::size`, just the name/identifier `size` which is known to `std::map` as being inherited from its base class. So, no, to the best of my knowledge you can't work your way around that.

Comment: not really what i was hoping for, but casting it is then.